# Farming the bunker

Tags: borderlands-2

I don't really know how to farm except keep turning off the game after you save and then fight him again so I need some farming tips and how to farm the bunker effectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can exit to Thousand Cuts and then re-enter to Bunker area and have him respawn, allowing you to fight him again, very useful when farming in co-op, since you don't need to end the session and wait everyone to re-join your game every time.

Be warned though, if you glitch kill the bunker with assassin B0re ability, he may get destroyed in mid air, throwing all the loot down the cliff, making them unobtainable, this also prevents bunker from respawning when re-entering the area.

For farming tips, I'd say having 1-2 players with bee shield and corrosive high fire rate weapons, firing from safe place while 1-2 players draw fire onto themselves, wearing shields with blast-proof prefixes, to reduce the damage from mortars and rockets.

Example:
Have siren and assassin using bee shields from cover and commando/gunzerker drawing all the fire onto themselves, allowing constant bee-damage from the others. After all, bee shield is only good as long as its fully charged.
Receiving even 1 point of damage makes it totally worthless piece of junk until its fully charged again.

Good team can take bunker down in few minutes even in ultimate vault hunter mode.
note that zero can use killing blow-> execution combo on near dead bunker, by teleporting into the air and reducing that 30% health instantly, making it even faster, just be careful not to fall of the cliff when flying into the sky with execution.

Bunker also has big critical hit locations, making it easy to score those crits.
Zer0's critical ascension really shines on this fight, combined with the bee shield which amp bonus is also multiplied by the criticals, this fight is a cake walk.
bonus points for using weapons with bonus critical hit damage.